# Extract Keys by Values

Tags: typescript

How can I get extract keys by values in Typescript?

So, let's say I have a test object that will have properties and methods

```js
interface Test {
    hello: () => 'Hello World!'
    test: 1
}

const test: Test = {
    hello () {
        return 'Hello World!'
    },
    test: 1
}
```

I could, for example, make a function that returns values from that test object based on its key.

```js
function getTestValue<Key extends keyof Test> (key: Key): Test[Key] {
    return test[key]
}
```

Now, what if I want to limit my function to only methods (functions)?

I could make it an error if `Test[Key]` is not a function but that feels more like a workaround than a proper solution.

```js
function getTestMethod<Key extends keyof Test> (key: Key): Test[Key] {
    const method = test[key]

    if (!isFunction(method)) throw new Error('Method is not a function')

    return method
}
```

In this case, IntelliSense will suggest **all** `Test` keys, including those that are not functions which might lead to bugs which is precisely what I am trying to avoid using Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

```js
type MethodKeyOf<T> = keyof {
    [Key in keyof T as T[Key] extends (...args: never) => unknown ? Key : never]: T[Key];
}

type KeysOfTest = MethodKeyOf<Test>; // "hello"

function getTestValue<Key extends MethodKeyOf<Test>> (key: Key): Test[Key] {
    return test[key]
}
```

[Sandbox](https://tsplay.dev/WYe1EW)

There are a few broadly equivalent syntaxes for it but the basic idea is to restrict to the keys that can be a function.

Comment: Your implementation of MethodKeyOf does not seem to work when I do `T[MethodKeyOf<T>]` as Typescript thinks there is no overlap between `MethodKeyOf<T>` and `keyof T` but altering slightly your code from having its values from `true` to `T[Key]` seems to fix the issue without any change in functionality

Comment: _sigh_, well caught. That's what I had originally! Edited back now.

Comment: It does not seem to work on types that extend other types, take [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wE80kW) for example, `type TestMethod = GetTestMethod<Test, 'hello'>` will work but if I make `TestMethod` accept anything that extends `Test` (like this: `type TestMethod<T extends Test> = GetTestMethod<T, 'hello'>`) it won't. Typescript says that `'hello'` can not index `FunctionKeys<T>` which seems very counterintuitive because `'hello'` can extend `FunctionKeys<Test>` and `T` extends `Test`.

Comment: Might depend on how is `GetTestMethod` is defined. Can you share the definition?

Comment: It should be defined on line 14 of [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/wE80kW) (`type GetTestMethod<T extends Test, Key extends FunctionKeys<T>> = T[Key]`)

Comment: There's something odd going on, although you can [work around it](https://tsplay.dev/mZZKEm) by explicitly `Extract`ing or intersecting `'hello'` with `FunctionKeys<T>`. Will have a bit of a play but it might just be bumping up against the limits of type inference.

Comment: Pretty sure it is "just the way TS works at the moment" with conditional types. Might be worth asking a new question to see if there are additional insights.